# for a polynomial $f(x)$, $y^3+f(x)$ can be written as the product of two polynomial iff $f=g^3$

Tags: polynomials

If f is a polynomial with one variable, then I want to prove that $y^3+f(x)$ can be written as the product of polynomials with positive degree if and only if there is a polynomial g(x) such that $f(x)=g(x)^3$, one direction is simple, if $f(x)=g(x)^3$ then $y^3+f(x)=(y+f(x))(y^2-yf(x)+f(x)^2)$, but how to prove the another direction? I have no clue, can anyone help me? thank you in advance, and also please help me in this question:[$f_{n}\left ( x,y \right )+f_{n-1}\left ( x,y \right )$ is irreducible for two homogeneous polynomials without common divisor.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4249103/f-n-left-x-y-right-f-n-1-left-x-y-right-is-irreducible-for-two-h)
thank you

Comment: what is $y$? A constant?

Comment: @miracle173  y is a variable

Comment: I think there's no difference between a constant an a variable. But it is independent of $x$. Is this true?

Comment: yes @miracle173

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $y^3+f$ is the product of two polynomials then these can polynomial factors be written as $y+a$ and $y^2+by+c$ where $a,b,c$ are polynomials in $x$.

So
$$(y+a)(y^2+by+c)=y^3+y^2(a+b)+y(ab+c)+ac=y^3+f$$

comparing the coefficients we get

$$a+b=0\\
ab+c=0\\
ac=f
$$
and further $b=-a$, $c=a^2$ and $f=a^3$